# Push Undefined syntax error JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I need to create a program that asks the user for a value to store in an array and continues to keep asking for values to add till they have no more numbers they want to enter into the array. Afterwards I must output the array containing no zeros (Which they're allowed to enter zeros so I have to filter them out from the output) and return the sum of the array. My current issue with my program is that `arr.push(x)` is currently trying to push an undefined value in the function arrin. I feel as if there's a much better way of going about this than I'm currently trying so I'm all ears for improvement.

```
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number, to exit enter NaN", "0"), 10);

var y = arrin(x); 

var arr = [];

var s;

function arrin(x) {

if(x != NaN){
    arr.push(x)
    x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number, to exit enter NaN", "0"), 10); 
    y = arrin(x);
}else{
    document.write("<p>"+arr.toString()+"</p>");
    s = sum(arr);
    doucment.write("<p> The sum of all elements in the array is "+s+"</p>");
}
```

}

Comment: you have a tail recursion easily avoidable with a `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x != NaN` will not work.

`!isNaN(x)` will check if the var is a number.

`x != "NaN"` will check if the text is literally "NaN"

either of the last two will work.

```js
var arr = [];
var y = arrin(0);
var s;

function arrin(x) {

  if (!isNaN(x)) {
    if (x != 0) arr.push(x)
    x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number, to exit enter NaN", "0"), 10);
    y = arrin(x);
  } else {
    document.write("<p>" + arr.toString() + "</p>");
    s = sum();
    document.write("<p> The sum of all elements in the array is " + s + "</p>");
  }
}

function sum() {
  var t = 0;
  for (var i = arr.length; i--;) t += parseInt(arr[i]);
  return t;
}
```